# Ensure URL is relative before navigating via JavaScript's location.replace()

Tags: javascript, url, xss

I have a login page `https://example.com/login#destination` where `destination` is the target URL the user was trying to navigate to when they were required to log in.
(i.e. `https://example.com/destination`)

The JavaScript I was thinking about using was

```
function onSuccessfulLogin() {
    location.replace(location.hash.substring(1) || 'default')
}
```

- This would result in an XSS vulnerability, by an attacker providing the link
  `https://example.com/login#javascript:..`
- Also I need to prevent navigation to a lookalike site after login.
  `https://example.com/login#https://looks-like-example.com`
  or `https://example.com/login#//looks-like-example.com`

How can I adjust `onSuccessfulLogin` to ensure the URL provided in the hash `#` portion is a relative URL, and not starting with `javascript:`, `https:`, `//` or any other absolute navigation scheme?

One thought is to evaluate the URL, and see if `location.origin` remains unchanged before navigating. Can you suggest how to do this, or a better approach?

Comment: first thought that occurred to me is make an ajax HEAD request...then in success do redirect

Comment: There is not enough data to work out a full solution, but to make things a bit simpler and more coder friendly, I could lend you my JavaScript Location constructor, which can be used in the following way.
`var loc = new Loc( sURL ); loc = loc.hash.split("#")[1];  
if( /javascript|http/i.test( loc.protocol ) ) {  loc.hash = default; location = loc.href };` but I still need a better clarification on the situation.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey, of course it's not - but if you haven't read it well: I my original reply I'm saying "that I could lend you mine" in case you like my proposition.

Comment: Also in your original request, you wanted to make sure it is not a JavaScript directive either. Therefore in case that you like the principle used in my illustration code (which checks for both javascript and absolute paths of your hash ) - I will post you the Loc  constructor function that you could add in your bag JS-Tools of the current project.  That I can do.

Comment: @Bekim, My apologies. That is alright, as I would prefer not to add a library for this purpose, because I can accomplish my goal more simply by pre-pending `'https://example.com/'` as suggested by Роман.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From OWASP recommendations on [Preventing Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet#Safe_URL_Redirects#Preventing_Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards):

> It is recommended that any such destination input be mapped to a value, *rather than the actual URL or portion of the URL*, and that server side code translate this value to the target URL.

So a safe approach would be mapping some keys to actual URLs:

```
// https://example.com/login#destination

var keyToUrl = {
  destination: 'https://example.com/destination',
  defaults: 'https://example.com/default'
};

function onSuccessfulLogin() {
  var hash = location.hash.substring(1);
  var url = keyToUrl[hash] || keyToUrl.defaults;

  location.replace(url);
}
```

You could also consider providing only path part of the URL and appending it with a hostname in the code:

```
// https://example.com/login#destination

function onSuccessfulLogin() {
  var path = location.hash.substring(1);
  var url = 'https://example.com/' + path;

  location.replace(url);
}
```

I would stick to the mapping though.

Comment: Ah, yes pre-pending `location.origin + '/'` (`https://example.com`) looks like a good solution. Sorry, but in this particular project we won't be using mappings, despite the extra value they would provide.

Answer (score 0):

That is a **very** good point about the XSS vulnerability.

I believe all protocols only use English alphabetic characters, so a regex like `/^[a-z]+:/i` would check for those. Alternately if we're feeling more inclusive, `/^[^:\/?]+:/` allows anything but a `/` or `?` followed by a `:`. Then we can combine that with `/^\/\/` to test for a protocol-free URL, which gives us:

```
// Either
var rexIsProtocol = /(?:^[a-z]+:)|(?:^\/\/)/i;
// Or
var rexIsProtocol = /(?:^[^:\/?]+:)|(?:^\/\/)/i;
```

Then the test is like this:

```
var url = location.hash.substring(1).trim(); // trim to deal with whitespace
if (rexIsProtocol.test(url)) {
    // It starts with a protocol
} else {
    // It doesn't
}
```

That said, the only one I think you need to be particularly bothered by is the `javascript:` pseudo-protcol, so you might just test for that.